# While loop doesnt want to give me particular variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a while loop that is showing photographs, and under are each one is a link throwing a popup and opening a form. The form is made to send a comment to the photograph.
Everything works here but I have a problem with photoid variable.
I have been trying for many days but the id of a photo never gets out correctly out of the loop.
Its always id of the last photo or of the first.... Could you please help me to do this?
People have been helping me with some jquery, ajax scripts, with some hidden input in form but this never worked for me, maybe i am too stupid :( 
Could you help me please take the id of the photo connected with "comments" link outside of the loop?
I am so tired of this....... Please!
I tagged it also as java script because i dont know what will be needed to finish this

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
//-----------------HERE BEGINS THE LOOP THROWING OUT PHOTOS--------------------
$allphotos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($numphotos = mysql_fetch_assoc($allphotos)){

    $photoinfo = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM photos WHERE link="'.$numphotos['link'].'" ');
    $fetchinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($photoinfo);
    //------------HERE IS PHOTO--------------------------
    echo '<img src="'.$numphotos['link'].'" alt="photo" class="photolink" align="middle">';

    $photoid = $fetchinfo['id'];
    //----------------BELOW IS THE ADD COMMENT LINK----------------
    echo " <div class='comments'><a href='#' class='my-button' onclick='komenty(".$photoid.")'>komentarze</a></div> ";
    //---------------------HERE STARTS THE POPUP ADDING COMMENT FORM-------------
    echo "
    <div id='element_to_pop_up'>
    <img src='' alt='photo' class='photolink' align='middle'>
    <form action='main.php' id='comments' method='post'>
    <textarea rows='8' cols='80' name='comments'></textarea> <br />
    <input type='hidden' name='photoid' value='".$photoid."'>
    <input type='submit' name='send' value='Wyślij'>
    </form>
    <a class='b-close'></a>
    </div>";

}
//----------------AFTER THE FORM IS SUBMITED THE CODE BELOW SAVES THE COMMENT TO DATABASE BUT THE PHOTOID IS ALWAYS NOT CORRECT---------
if (isset($_POST['send'])){   
    try{
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (comment, photoid, writer, date) VALUES (:comment, :photoid, :writer, :date) ");
        $stmt->execute(array('comment'=> $_POST['comments'], 'photoid'=> $_POST['photoid'], 'writer'=> $_GLOBALS['nick'], 'date'=> date("Y-m-d")));
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'error main.php 1:' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

?>
```

The function below doesnt really matter but I am adding it as you wish:

```
function komenty(photoid) {
    var xmlhttp=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "comments.php?id=" + photoid, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            x = xmlhttp.responseText;
            $.get( "main.php", {x: x});

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT popup js code:

```
    // Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
    // Encapsulation
    // $ is assigned to jQuery
    ;(function($) {

         // DOM Ready
        $(function() {

            // Binding a click event
            // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
            $('.my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

                // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
               // e.preventDefault();

                // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
                $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();

            });

        });

    })(jQuery);

/*================================================================================
 * @name: bPopup - if you can't get it up, use bPopup
 * @author: (c)Bjoern Klinggaard (twitter@bklinggaard)
 * @demo: http://dinbror.dk/bpopup
 * @version: 0.9.4.min
 ================================================================================*/
 (function(b){b.fn.bPopup=function(z,F){function K(){a.contentContainer=b(a.contentContainer||c);switch(a.content){case "iframe":var h=b('<iframe class="b-iframe" '+a.iframeAttr+"></iframe>");h.appendTo(a.contentContainer);r=c.outerHeight(!0);s=c.outerWidth(!0);A();h.attr("src",a.loadUrl);k(a.loadCallback);break;case "image":A();b("<img />").load(function(){k(a.loadCallback);G(b(this))}).attr("src",a.loadUrl).hide().appendTo(a.contentContainer);break;default:A(),b('<div class="b-ajax-wrapper"></div>').load(a.loadUrl,a.loadData,function(){k(a.loadCallback);G(b(this))}).hide().appendTo(a.contentContainer)}}function A(){a.modal&&b('<div class="b-modal '+e+'"></div>').css({backgroundColor:a.modalColor,position:"fixed",top:0,right:0,bottom:0,left:0,opacity:0,zIndex:a.zIndex+t}).appendTo(a.appendTo).fadeTo(a.speed,a.opacity);D();c.data("bPopup",a).data("id",e).css({left:"slideIn"==a.transition||"slideBack"==a.transition?"slideBack"==a.transition?g.scrollLeft()+u:-1*(v+s):l(!(!a.follow[0]&&m||f)),position:a.positionStyle||"absolute",top:"slideDown"==a.transition||"slideUp"==a.transition?"slideUp"==a.transition?g.scrollTop()+w:x+-1*r:n(!(!a.follow[1]&&p||f)),"z-index":a.zIndex+t+1}).each(function(){a.appending&&b(this).appendTo(a.appendTo)});H(!0)}function q(){a.modal&&b(".b-modal."+c.data("id")).fadeTo(a.speed,0,function(){b(this).remove()});a.scrollBar||b("html").css("overflow","auto");b(".b-modal."+e).unbind("click");g.unbind("keydown."+e);d.unbind("."+e).data("bPopup",0<d.data("bPopup")-1?d.data("bPopup")-1:null);c.undelegate(".bClose, ."+a.closeClass,"click."+e,q).data("bPopup",null);H();return!1}function G(h){var b=h.width(),e=h.height(),d={};a.contentContainer.css({height:e,width:b});e>=c.height()&&(d.height=c.height());b>=c.width()&&(d.width=c.width());r=c.outerHeight(!0);s=c.outerWidth(!0);D();a.contentContainer.css({height:"auto",width:"auto"});d.left=l(!(!a.follow[0]&&m||f));d.top=n(!(!a.follow[1]&&p||f));c.animate(d,250,function(){h.show();B=E()})}function L(){d.data("bPopup",t);c.delegate(".bClose, ."+a.closeClass,"click."+e,q);a.modalClose&&b(".b-modal."+e).css("cursor","pointer").bind("click",q);M||!a.follow[0]&&!a.follow[1]||d.bind("scroll."+e,function(){B&&c.dequeue().animate({left:a.follow[0]?l(!f):"auto",top:a.follow[1]?n(!f):"auto"},a.followSpeed,a.followEasing)}).bind("resize."+e,function(){w=y.innerHeight||d.height();u=y.innerWidth||d.width();if(B=E())clearTimeout(I),I=setTimeout(function(){D();c.dequeue().each(function(){f?b(this).css({left:v,top:x}):b(this).animate({left:a.follow[0]?l(!0):"auto",top:a.follow[1]?n(!0):"auto"},a.followSpeed,a.followEasing)})},50)});a.escClose&&g.bind("keydown."+e,function(a){27==a.which&&q()})}function H(b){function d(e){c.css({display:"block",opacity:1}).animate(e,a.speed,a.easing,function(){J(b)})}switch(b?a.transition:a.transitionClose||a.transition){case "slideIn":d({left:b?l(!(!a.follow[0]&&m||f)):g.scrollLeft()-(s||c.outerWidth(!0))-C});break;case "slideBack":d({left:b?l(!(!a.follow[0]&&m||f)):g.scrollLeft()+u+C});break;case "slideDown":d({top:b?n(!(!a.follow[1]&&p||f)):g.scrollTop()-(r||c.outerHeight(!0))-C});break;case "slideUp":d({top:b?n(!(!a.follow[1]&&p||f)):g.scrollTop()+w+C});break;default:c.stop().fadeTo(a.speed,b?1:0,function(){J(b)})}}function J(b){b?(L(),k(F),a.autoClose&&setTimeout(q,a.autoClose)):(c.hide(),k(a.onClose),a.loadUrl&&(a.contentContainer.empty(),c.css({height:"auto",width:"auto"})))}function l(a){return a?v+g.scrollLeft():v}function n(a){return a?x+g.scrollTop():x}function k(a){b.isFunction(a)&&a.call(c)}function D(){x=p?a.position[1]:Math.max(0,(w-c.outerHeight(!0))/2-a.amsl);v=m?a.position[0]:(u-c.outerWidth(!0))/2;B=E()}function E(){return w>c.outerHeight(!0)&&u>c.outerWidth(!0)}b.isFunction(z)&&(F=z,z=null);var a=b.extend({},b.fn.bPopup.defaults,z);a.scrollBar||b("html").css("overflow","hidden");var c=this,g=b(document),y=window,d=b(y),w=y.innerHeight||d.height(),u=y.innerWidth||d.width(),M=/OS 6(_\d)+/i.test(navigator.userAgent),C=200,t=0,e,B,p,m,f,x,v,r,s,I;c.close=function(){a=this.data("bPopup");e="__b-popup"+d.data("bPopup")+"__";q()};return c.each(function(){b(this).data("bPopup")||(k(a.onOpen),t=(d.data("bPopup")||0)+1,e="__b-popup"+t+"__",p="auto"!==a.position[1],m="auto"!==a.position[0],f="fixed"===a.positionStyle,r=c.outerHeight(!0),s=c.outerWidth(!0),a.loadUrl?K():A())})};b.fn.bPopup.defaults={amsl:50,appending:!0,appendTo:"body",autoClose:!1,closeClass:"b-close",content:"ajax",contentContainer:!1,easing:"swing",escClose:!0,follow:[!0,!0],followEasing:"swing",followSpeed:500,iframeAttr:'scrolling="no" frameborder="0"',loadCallback:!1,loadData:!1,loadUrl:!1,modal:!0,modalClose:!0,modalColor:"#000",onClose:!1,onOpen:!1,opacity:0.7,position:["auto","auto"],positionStyle:"absolute",scrollBar:!0,speed:250,transition:"fadeIn",transitionClose:!1,zIndex:9997}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You use only one one comment form for all photos or every photo has own comment form?

Comment: @SamuelKelemen It seems like every photo got its own form because its also looped

Comment: Why are you mixing `mysql` and `PDO` in the same script?

Comment: @LetMeLearn123 yes but every form has same id. And why is img src in this popup empty? It seems like it is filled with javascript after anchor click. So maybe after that click you dont change value for form hidden photoid field.

Comment: @Barmar This is my first PDO thing ever. I am learning it because you told me to sir :D

Comment: Why do two queries, why not do a join that gets the linked photo at the same time as the first photo?

Comment: Can you provide you javascript code operates with popup?

Comment: Are you sure `$photoid` isn't being set correctly? What do you see if you `View Source`?

Comment: I suspect the problem you're having is becaue you reuse the same `id=element_to_pop_up` for every DIV. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: @Barmar In source i see different IDs, but when i press "send" in form and check the database the IDs are all the same, i dont understand this xD

Comment: Please add the `komenty()` function to your question.

Comment: @Barmar the komenty() was made to read out the comments from the database but it was problematic too. Anyway it doesnt matter i think since i cant even add a comment :D

Comment: @SamuelKelemen I deleted the img src because it was a variable and had some problems with it too haha it was everytime showing different photo XD

Comment: Are you doing normal form submission, or are you using AJAX?

Comment: @Barmar are you asking about this comments form? It is just submited normally. But i am getting confused by my own written code  I am not very advanced coder as you can see :(

Comment: @SamuelKelemen I am not sure how to add the js code of the popup. This is a very long addtional file

Comment: Could you clarify: the problem is when you click on the comment button, or when you click on the Send button in the form? `komenty()` is all wrong -- you shouldn't call `xmlhttp.open` and `xmlhttp.send` inside the `onreadystatechange` function, you have to call them immediately -- the `onreadystatechange` function is run when the response comes back.

Comment: The problem in your popup code is that you use the same `element_to_pop_up` ID for every form. IDs must be unique. `$("#element_to_pop_up")` will always select the first instance of that ID, which will not be the same as the one associated with the button you clicked on.

Comment: @Barmar Sir, i am almost sure that the problems is the popup. It there is used id instead of class. I tried to change #element_to_pop_up into .element_to_pop_up in my code and in js pop up scripts but i messed something up. The popup stopped working but i see the forms on the main page without clicking "comment link" and they are working well and sending the right photoid! I have just no idea now how to make the popup work with it xD I added the popup code in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs have to be unique. You should change `id="element_to_pop_up"` to `class="element_to_pop_up"`. Then change the popup JS to use DOM traversal to find the adjacent DIV to pop up:

```
;(function($) {

     // DOM Ready
    $(function() {

        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('.my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
           // e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $(this).closest(".comment").next('.element_to_pop_up').bPopup();

        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The popup windows still not working now, the forms are just looped and i see them on a main page. But you helped me a lot my friend. The IDs are correct now, you are the best !

Comment: You have two things running when you click on the button: `komenty()` because of the `onclick`, and `bPopup` because of this code.

Comment: Wow i didnt notice that lane with "closest". This is truly awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm but i cant click twice on the same comment link without reloading the website. This is pretty strange

Comment: Can you post a link to your website?

Comment: www.czyjestemladna.pl  There is a short registration but email activation is not needed so you can do it very quickly

Comment: When the popup closes, it's being removed from the DOM for some reason. But this doesn't happen with the sample fiddle on the bPopup web site.

Comment: At least now i know what happens. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The variable '$photoinfo' might be fetching multiple rows so I added LIMIT to mysql statment.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
//-----------------HERE BEGINS THE LOOP THROWING OUT PHOTOS--------------------
$allphotos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($numphotos = mysql_fetch_assoc($allphotos)){
    // Added
    $photoinfo = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM photos WHERE link="'.$numphotos['link'].'" LIMIT 1');
    $fetchinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($photoinfo);
//------------HERE IS PHOTO--------------------------
    echo '<img src="'.$numphotos['link'].'" alt="photo" class="photolink" align="middle">';

    $photoid = ($fetchinfo['id']) ? $fetchinfo['id'] : '';
//----------------BELOW IS THE ADD COMMENT LINK----------------
    echo "<div class='comment_wrapper'>";
    echo " <div class='comments'><a href='#' class='my-button'>komentarze</a></div> ";
//---------------------HERE STARTS THE POPUP ADDING COMMENT FORM-------------
    echo "
    <div class='element_to_pop_up'>
        <img src='' alt='photo' class='photolink' align='middle'>
        <form action='main.php' id='comments' method='post'>
            <textarea rows='8' cols='80' name='comments'></textarea> <br />
            <input type='hidden' name='photoid' value='".$photoid."'>
            <input type='submit' name='send' value='Wyślij'>
        </form>
        <a class='b-close'></a>
    </div>";

    echo "</div>";

}
```

Also you have not included komenty() function, I've written few lines of jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".my-button" ).click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.element_to_pop_up').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed, don't just dump a bunch of code.

Comment: @Barmar Looks like he added a lane that makes photoid variable empty at the beginning of the loop

Comment: That's totally useless, since he reassigns the variable 4 lines later, and never uses the variable in between.

Comment: @Barmar It changed the photoid just one time. But i am happy anyway, finally something new happend hahah :D But you are right, now it still stays the same. I feel so hopeless I spent like a week on it so far :(

Comment: Adding `LIMIT 1` won't change anything. He's only calling `mysql_fetch_assoc` once, so even if it returns multiple rows, he only uses the first one.